# How do I package a new TFS Service Hook?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I have created a new type of Service Hook for TFS.  Does anyone know how to create a VSIX package for it so that it can be installed into Team Foundation Server?  The current deployment model is just to drop it into the Application Tier bin/Plugins directory which is not ideal.

There's reasonable guidance on how to package a build task or extension on the web but nothing for Service Hooks or server-side plugins.

Comment: How do you create a new type of service hook for TFS?

Comment: That wasn't particularly obvious either, but basically you have to derive from Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.ServiceHooks.Common.ConsumerImplementation and ConsumerActionImplementation and expose your implementations using the MEF attributes.  Drop the resulting assembly in the bin/Plugins directory on the Application Tier and your service hook will get picked up by TFS.  There are some built-in implementations that you can examine already in the Plugins directory (ILSpy is your friend here).

Answer (score 0):

Install service hooks or server plugin through extension is not supported. I submit a [user voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/16316488-tfs-service-hooks-or-server-side-plugins-installat) that you could  vote it.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the answer.  How annoying :-(

Comment: @jamesmus This feature may be added if many customers require.